# Python encoding with csvwriter and urllib

Tags: python, csv, encoding

I know similar questions have been answered by the bucketload here, but none of the methods offered really fixed my problem.

What I am trying to do:

I get a lot of data from webpages and parse them in Python, the write the results to CSV files.

The code that I am using right now is akin to:

```
with urllib.request.urlopen('http://xxxxxx.com.br/') as response:
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.read().decode('utf-8','replace'), 'html.parser')

#lots of parsing here

with open('exit.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    exit_writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=';', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    for cat in categories:
        exit_writer.writerow([a.encode('utf-8') for a in cat])
```

The code runs, but it will always begin the cells/strings with b' and all special characters will be replaced by code like \xe2\x80\x93

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix this for good?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean 'replaced'? If you encode u'—', the em dash `u+2013`, you end up with UTF-8 bytes `\xe2\x80\x93`. Isn't this exactly what you're asking in the last line? Can you please give comprehensive examples of what looks wrong, and what it should have been?

Comment: @9000
An example: a cell reads should read "Bacharel em relações internacionais" but instead reads "b'Bacharel em Rela\xc3\xa7\xc3\xb5es Internacionais'"
doublequotes added by me.
I do understand that this is the utf-8 encoded bytestring, but if I don´t do the "a.encode('utf-8')" on the last line of code, I run into those famous "maps to undefined" errors

Comment: It looks like you call `repr`somewhere, or pass an object that interpolates this way, instead of getting a string value out of it. E.g. are you sure you always extract text from BeautifulSoup objects, and don't pass nodes to output instead? I'd add a bunch of print statements along the way and look where the wrong representation creeps in.